# Get current time in seconds using moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to get the current time in seconds. I am really struggling, and apologize for asking what is probably a simple problem.

I have this so far:

```
const time = await moment().format("hh:mm:ss");
// current time: 11:17:21

expires_in:'3599' (string)
```

The `expires_in` is provided from an api call that is given to me in seconds. For example, `3599` (which is about an hour when converted from seconds to minuets).

I want to get the current time (from the client) convert that to seconds. 
Then I'd like to add the `expires_in` to the current time. If that time is > then the current time, I know I need to request a new token.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `add` method to add `expires_in` seconds to your time.

```js
const date = moment(),
      curr = +moment(),
      time = date.format("hh:mm:ss"),
      expires_in = '3599',
      newTime = date.add(expires_in, 'seconds').format("hh:mm:ss"),
      expires = +date.add(expires_in, 'seconds');
console.log(time, newTime);
console.log(curr, expires, curr > expires);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hassan, thank you so much for such a detailed answer. I am going through it line by line to get a better understanding of what you're doing. I really appreciate the time you took!